# InputText with only numbers using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, seam

I've been trying to make a input text to fill up with only numbers, i'm using jQuery to do(try...) this job

```
<rich:jQuery selector="#code" query="mask('9999999999')"/>
```

This isn't working.. any idea of what can I do?
Can I set max value? for example: max value is 2147483647

Comment: You could use [`<input type="number" min="0" max="2147483647" />`](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-number) if you're able to use html 5 `form` elements.

Comment: <h:inputText id="code" value="#{someClass.someObject.code}" size="10"/>
There's no type on it, is there anything that I could do on it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried LiveValidation?
[LiveValidation.com](http://livevalidation.com/examples#exampleNumericality)

```
var myNumberField = new LiveValidation('myNumberField');
myNumberField.add( Validate.Numericality );
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery alphanumeric](http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)

```
<rich:jQuery selector="#code" query="numeric()"/>
```